# Microsoft demo database copyright, open source demo databases?

Tags: database, testing, demo, database-testing

In my open source project which is licensed under [LGPLv3](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html) I need a small demo database. Project targets multiple databases so for consistency of tests it would be great to have some simple SQL script with same demo data for all databases.

There is a small demo database for SQL Server provided by Microsoft, it's calles *pubs* (goes in demo database packge for SQL Server 2000 along with *Northwind*). It comes in two flavors: as SQL script and drop-in database file. Script is copyrighted as follows:

```
/*                                                                        */
/*              InstPubs.SQL - Creates the Pubs database                  */ 
/*                                                                        */
/*
** Copyright Microsoft, Inc. 1994 - 2000
** All Rights Reserved.
*/
```

I've modified a script to generate database with same data for SQLite. But now I've realised that this probably wasn't a very good idea. So, I want to clarify some questions:

1. Can and should I include original SQL-script/MDF file Microsoft script in my project retaining copyright?
2. Can and should I include modified SQL-script/sqlite database, and if yes who will own copiright on that script/database?
3. Is there any open source demo database which I can use for my purposes (include and modify SQL script)? [This one](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila.html), for example?

I'm almost sure that the answer is 'NO' for first two ones, and 'YES' for the third. But I'm not sure yet.

**Update:**
Found two more bases [BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/db/) and [Chinook](http://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/) first is Eclipse license, second is MS-PL, I'm again not sure if I can use them.

**Update 2:**
Seems like it's not such a big deal. I realised that I can use independent licenses for different parts of code. Since it's not an essential part of a project code, but just a test database, I can work and include it using it's original license BSD, Eclipse, MS-PL whatever.

So the main question now is, which I should use? Conditions are it must be rather simple (about 10 tables) and script should be executed on most db engines without major modifications. [Chinook](http://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/) seems like an ideal choice, but it't not from a major software provider, I would like to use some already popular and "tested" database.

**Final update:**
After some re/searching I've gived up idea of having *one test database to rule then all* since this extremely limits some features of database engines and test become unrealistic. So I would go with different databases for each engine. As for MS database, I think it's just paranoia and MS probably won't sue me for anything :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just write your own?  Sounds like it would take less time that the trouble this copyright issue is causing you (especially for such a small database requirement).  A few examples could be the ubiquitous blog, a discussion forum etc.

Comment: I've considered this solution, but using a database created by other person is prefferable for testing purposes. Maybe I will start a fork of some available project instead.

Comment: I mark this as an answer since it's shows most effort (as the only one :) for now).